# Add iOS Close Button Icon Without Custom Image

Tags: ios, icons

Is there a custom X or close button icon builtin to iOS7 that can be used for a close button?

Comment: No, there is not any control in iOS 7.

Comment: But you can create your own using the character "x" and set the borders and corners to look like a button.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The closest built-in icon / image that looks like an **X** or a **Close Button** on iOS 7 is the `UIBarButtonItemSystemStop` image. Here is a link to the [documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW2). Below is the system image (which I image can be tinted using the iOS 7 `tint` parameter):

[image: UIBarButtonItemSystemStop]

You can also create your own - graphically in Photoshop or simply using text (which would fit the iOS 7 design). Just a fancied up **X** will do! Even a UIBarButtonItem with an "X" and then set the style to *Done* will give a bolded X.

Another (private) real-iOS example is from UIKit's private resources - the iAd close button. Try using an app like [iOS Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor) to search for and download UIKit images. The images in UIKit are owned by Apple; so you'll need to create your own. You can use the images provided there for inspiration, and then create your own thing in Photoshop.

Comment: I dont see UIBarButtonItemSystemStop?

Comment: @MikeFlynn it looks like it will only show up on a `UIToolbar` when you set the `UIBarButtonItem` type to `UIBarButtonItemSystemStop`. And Apple may not offer the *stop* item directly from Xcode IB, you may have to set it as *refresh* and then change it in the code.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a "stop" button as an "X" button; you're coupling two different use cases since by coincidence they look alike — what happens when Apple changes their asset to a "stop playing" string? Then all your "X" buttons all of a sudden will be updated to an unrelated string.

Comment: Good point @Zorayr - they could change the stop icon any iOS update so a few years from now the app might suddenly look bad. Better to avoid that.

Answer (score 13):

Of course it is possible.

```
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:(UIBarButtonSystemItemStop) 
                         target:self 
                         action:@selector(doneButtonTapped:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = closeButton;
```

It gives you a built-in 'X' button as the image shows.

[image: x button]

Successful tested under Xcode 5 and iOS 7.

> QUOTE FROM Sam:
>
> Even a UIBarButtonItem with an "X" and then set the style to Done will give a bolded X.

Although it works, the visual effect is ugly and users will feel it.

Answer (score 7):

The letter X is not visually appealing but the symbol **×** should work pretty well.

```
let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "×", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: Selector(""))
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(40)
buttonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: font], forState: .Normal)
```

Only I can't get the vertical alignment right.. Not even with:

```
buttonItem.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, 10), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

[image]

Comment: Goed zo Koen. Gewoon simpel houden.

The problem with this approach is that if you change the font height it will no longer align with the regular buttons. I couldn't change this neither. Interesting problem on itself. However the × symbol works perfect in a UIButton.

Answer (score 5):

use `UIBarButtonItem` and set it's style `UIBarButtonSystemItemStop` can give you an X button.
but i'm not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

The unicode ╳ character is close (in situations where you must use `UIButton` rather than `UIBarButtonItem` and thus cannot use the other solutions listed here).

Comment: I use the emoji ✕ , looks even closer.

Answer (score 1):

This a tricky subject. Ideally you might want to get an icon generated from  [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com) to get a more pixel perfect version.

What I have used myself is a "*Add Contact*" button type and then used this code to initialise it at load time to rotate it 45 degrees:

```
yourUILabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 4)
```

It's not an ideal solution in my option though.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 13 +**

We can use multiple inbuilt types, including close:

```
UIButton(type: .close)
```

For more information on button types please view:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/buttontype

Answer (score 0):

I ended up liking a lower cased "x" in Gill Sans at 40.0.  It's not perfect but it does the trick.
[image]

There is also a circled x in Xcode>Edit>Emojis if you search for "X" that could work.
[image]